# Error making N queen with stack "return value 3221225477"

Tags: c++

I'm going to make an N-queen with a stack.
However, There's a problem with the chords.
The console window says "return value 3221225477"
I searched it was a scanf problem, but I'm not
It hasn't been long since I learned coding, so the code is inefficient and complicated. I'm so sorry.
Please give me a kind explanation.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stack>
#include <math.h>

int n, col[11], k = 1; 

void output(){
    for(int i = 1; i<=n; i++)
        printf("(%d, %d)",i,col[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
int main()
{
    std::stack <int> S; 
    int check, flag = 1, i = 1;
    scanf(" %d", &n);
    for(int j = 1; j <= n;j++)
        S.push(n-j+1);
    while(!S.empty())
    {
        while(S.top() == 0)
        {
            S.pop(); 
            printf("%d",k);
            k--; 
        }
        check = 0;
        col[k] = S.top();
        if(k == n)
            output();
        if(!S.empty())
            S.pop();
        for(int j = 1; j <= n && k < n; j++)
        {
            flag = 1;
            i = 1;
            while(i < k+1){
                if((abs(i-(k+1)) == abs(col[i]-j)) || (col[i] == j))
                    flag  = 0;
                i++;
            }   
            if(flag == 1)
            {               
                if(check == 0)
                {
                    S.push(0);
                    k++;
                    check = 1;
                }
                S.push(j);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the value of `n`? Array indices go from 0 till size-1

Comment: Did you try to debug the code? Why not?

Comment: `while(S.top() == 0) { S.pop();...}` -- What happens if `S.pop()` causes the stack to be empty?  The next `S.top()` will cause undefined behavior.  That should be `while (!S.empty() && S.top() == 0)`

Comment: `for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)` : array indexes start at 0, not at 1. Not sureif this is the actual problem, but it definitely is a problem.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number n is the size of the chessboard.

Comment: what is its value? Please include input, output and expected output in the question

Comment: btw you are mixing C and C++. Each of them is difficult enough on their own, you shouldnt mix them when not necessary. If you learned to write code like this from some tutorial, then you need to find better material to learn actual C++ (see eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I concur; alas it only prolongs the inevitable. Two lines after that broken while-loop ends `S.top()` is blindly referenced anyway. This algorithm needs a review and some TLC, and above all, the OP needs to stop fighting 0-based indexing and embrace it as part of the language.